# postgresql compare two databases add missing columns

Tags: database, postgresql, compare, addition

I have two identical databases, let's say:

```
databasemaster: ID (int) , NAME (charactervariying(30)) , SURNAME(charactervarying(30))

database1: ID (int) , NAME (charactervariying(30)) , SURNAME(charactervarying(30))
```

I am adding a column to  databasemaster let's say, (charactervariying(50)) ,

AIM: I want to have a postgresql script/function which compares itself with masterdb and  adds the charactervariying(50) column to them. I want script to find the lastly added column dynamically.

How could I do that?

Comment: These are separate databases, not just separate schemas, correct?

Comment: yes, these are separate dbs.